# HTML select tag animation for its options

Tags: html, angular, css, animate.css, angular-animations

How to animate `<select>` list on opening it by using `fadeInDown` of `animate.css`? I don't want to use `<ul>` tag and jQuery for this purpose as I am using angular with typescript.

Comment: select,radio,checkbox etc are elements handled by the browser. You cannot change the default behavior. What you can do is make a custom element/component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't animate options from a select tag (or I'm not aware of it).

For all I know, this is handled directly by the browser. That's why you can't style the options either.

If you want to animate it and style the options, you will have to make custom component, such as the [**Material dropdown select**](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)

Comment: yeah i couldn't find anything related animating select tag, other way is to use angular animations.

Comment: @AsadShah Angular animations aren't magical, they rely on CSS, which means it won't correct your issue.